# Pandas .filter() method with lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to understand the [.filter()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) method in Pandas. I'm not sure why the below code doesn't work:

```
# Load data
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

# Set arbitrary index (is this needed?) and try filtering:
indexed_df = df.copy().set_index('sepal width (cm)')
test = indexed_df.filter(lambda x: x['petal length (cm)'] > 1.4)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

I appreciate there are simpler ways to do this (e.g. Boolean indexing) but I'm trying to understand for learning purposes why `filter` fails here when it works for a `groupby` as shown below:

This works:

```
 filtered_df = df.groupby('petal width (cm)').filter(lambda x: x['sepal width (cm)'].sum() > 50)
```

Comment: The documentation where you link to has four arguments: `items`, `like`, `regex` and `axis`. None of the (if you read the documentation) accepts a function/lambda expression.

Comment: `filter` is for selecting columns based on partial matches and regex matches on the column names.

Comment: You should just be using plain ol' boolean indexing.

Comment: Thank you Willem (and others). I can happily do via Boolean indexing - the sole reason I asked is that it was an example from a DataCamp course, albeit using `groupby` and then `filter` with a `lambda` function. This part is still unclear to me as it works with a `groupby` - I will edit the question to make this explicit.

Comment: To be clear, this is not an exact duplicate of a Boolean indexing question, it's about why `filter` works with a `groupby` and not without.

Comment: @maw501 `DataFrame.filter` and `groupby.filter` are very different methods. Yes it is unfortunate that they have the same name but that's the only thing in common. You shouldn't compare them.

Comment: Goodness. I hadn't realised there was a `groupby.filter` - thanks! Maybe make that the answer? Thank you again.

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE... Is there a way to filter a DataFrame using a lambda?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the condition `indexed_df['petal length (cm)'] > 1.4` (here we use `indexed_df`, not `x`) as a way to filter the dataframe, so:

```
indexed_df[indexed_df['petal length (cm)'] > 1.4]
```

**How does this work?**

If you perform `indexed_df['petal length (cm)']` you obtain the "*column*" of the dataframe: some sort of sequence where for every index, we get the value of that column. By performing a `column > 1.4`, we obtain some sort of column of booleans: `True` if the condition is met for a certain row, and `False` otherwise.

We then can use such boolean column as an element for the dataframe `indexed_df[boolean_column]` to obtain only the rows where the corresponding row of the `boolean_column` is `True`.

Comment: Thanks but as stated above this doesn't clear up why the lambda function works when using with `groupby` as now included in the edited answer.